# How to deploy java.policy changes in IBM Notes

Tags: java, xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

In a recent project it was necessary to make adjustments to the java.policy of the IBM Notes Client (9.0.1). You may find the java.policy in a directory similar to:

```
C:\Program Files\IBM\Domino\jvm\lib\security\
```

I've added the following line to the main grant{}-block:

```
permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "getenv.TIKA_CONFIG";
```

This adjustment must be made to all customer-clients.
My question is:

How can I deploy these changes at the customers environment? Is there a IBM Domino configuration tool or something similar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short: don't.
Long: the policy file will be overwritten on every install or upgrade. Create a java.pol file instead. Use LotusScript to deploy. Full instructions here: http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-8JYAT5

Comment: Thank you! Your article leads me to this also very interessting [blog post](http://www.dalsgaard-data.eu/blog/java-security-in-ibm-domino/). As you suggested, I'll create and use java.pol instead of java.policy.

Comment: Thank you also for this one! [Don't try this at home](http://notessensei.com/blog/2013/05/dont-try-this-at-home.html)